# Why the published app on playstore are force closing on android 6.0

Tags: smartface.io

Hi I installed my published app on android 6.0 but the app always force close please give a solution to it or solve the problem please. I am using smartface 4.4.0.3 and the app is not opening on marshmallow android 6.0 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new release of Android (6.0) is going to be supported by Smartface, it is not right now.
It is in development phase and will be ready in approximately one month.

Comment: [link]smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-download-upload[\link] [link]smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/admob [/link] both this tutorials are not working in smartface so please do the needful in next update.

Comment: @merverbıçakçı  
[link]smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-download-upload[\link] [link]smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/admob [/link] both this tutorials are not working in smartface so please do the needful in next update.

Comment: There is a known issue in AdMob plugin and with the upcoming setup (450) plugin structure will change, and AdMob will be available for use again. And for file upload-download problem, again the structure will change with Smartface 450. Assets folder will be in use, and it will fix this issue. Thank you for your reports.

Comment: @merverbıçakçı Thank You also do change in webview control because webview can't open gallery or camera in android but works in ios do changes in android.

Comment: @merverbıçakçı Notifications.LocalNotification is not working in and the app is force closing always please see through it.